# Jekyll: How to {% include code-snippet.html %} while html-escaping code-snippet.html

Tags: jekyll

I want to host some API documentation example code snippets, where the snippets live in different files and are `include`d into a Jekyll page. I'm using Jekyll `include` tag (https://jekyllrb.com/docs/includes/).

e.g. given this input:

```html
The `br` tag is for line breaks. Example:
<pre>
{% include code-snippet.html %}
</pre>
```

And `code-snippet.html` might be like:

```html
<!doctype html>
First line<br>
Second line
```

I get this output, which has the browser interpreting the tags as HTML:

```html
The `<br>` tag is for line breaks. Example:
<pre>
<!doctype html>
First line<br>
Second line
</pre>
```

But I'd rather get this output, with the browser interpreting the tags as text:

```html
The `<br>` tag is for line breaks. Example:
<pre>
&lt;!doctype html&gt;
First line&lt;br&gt;
Second line
</pre>
```

Is there a way to achive this in Jekyll? Is there something like `{% include code-snippet.html | htmlEscape %}`? I imagine I could fix this with a Ruby plugin (after all, [the `include` tag is just Ruby](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/43a8a4666d3013d40dcefca351c618de1a5b9e1f/lib/jekyll/tags/include.rb#L273)), but I'd like to avoid writing a plugin if possible.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround:

You can read the [`include`](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/includes/) into a variable using [`capture`](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/includes/), then include the variable through the [`xml_escape`](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/filters/)https://jekyllrb.com/docs/includes/ filter:

```
{% capture code_snippet %}
{% include code-snippet.html %}
{% endcapture %}
<pre>
{{ code_snippet | xml_escape }}
</pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `highlight` tag also does HTML-escaping:

```
{% highlight html %}
{% include code-snippet.html %}
{% endhighlight %}
```